# Why we use iterator categories instead of just overloading for iterators accordingly?

Tags: c++, templates, iterator, overloading, traits

Consider a typical (simplified) implementation of `std::advance` function for iterators:

```
template<typename Iterator,typename Dist>
void advance(Iterator& it, Dist n) 
{
    typedef std::iterator_traits<Itarator>::iterator_category c;
    advance_impl(it, n, c);
}

template<typename Iterator, typename Dist>
void advance_impl(Iterator& it, Dist n, std::random_access_iterator_tag)
{
    it += n;
}

template<typename Iterator, typename Dist>
void advance_impl(Iterator& it, Dist n, std::input_iterator_tag)
{
    while (n--)++it;
}
```

I know that we can write all `advance_impl` in one function with branching using `constexpr if`, but let’s leave that for a moment.

Why do we use this instead of just overloading `std::advance` for corresponding iterators? Why do we need traits at all here?

Comment: How will you have overloads for 3rd party library types youve never heard of? with traits this all works

Comment: How many iterators are there to overload for? And what if we want to look beyond the standard library alone, how many are there now?

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica, I see. You mean we can combine a family of iterators under one overloaded trait?

Comment: @EduardRostomyan - Yes. This is the generic programming at its core, to categorize types by their properties and write algorithms once for each category.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica, Tgot the point, thanks. One more Q. Does this mean that all unknown types must have implemented the inner category as a property in order to be categorised for particular algorithms?

Comment: I believe these traits will become obsolete when concepts will be used.

Comment: Previously custom types needed to add members to be classified correctly, yes. Then `itarator_traits` was added, and so custom types can simply specialize that, instead of adding members they may not want. And like Slava said, C++20 concepts can take some of the burden here too.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica I think concepts not only can take some of the burden but will change it dramatically - you can define requirements on the type instead of relying on additional info defined somewhere else which is error prone. And that how it should be done in the first place but was not possible in C++ so using traits is a workaround.

Comment: @Slava That could be done with detection idioms even before concepts. In fact, concepts are for the most part, very nice syntax sugar.

Comment: @PasserBy maybe it could be done, but I would like to see it for example how you detect that raw pointer works as random access iterator. Anyway if I write a library I would like clear syntax to define type requirements instead of using "detection idioms" and end up in psychiatric clinic.

Comment: @Slava `template<class T> using random_access_t = decltype(std::declval<T>() + 42); template<class T> constexpr bool is_random_access = std::experimental::is_detected_v<random_access_t, T>;`

Comment: @PasserBy so `int` is a random access iterator? Hmm.

Comment: @Slava You could have all sorts of broken "iterators" even with concepts, the system is reliant on the programmer not trying to break it. Also the sarcasm isn't appreciated.

Comment: @PasserBy yes you could, but with properly defined concepts you can specify what iterator is and what it is not. Does `is_detected` allow type extention like random access iterator is bidirectional iterator + those operations? Where bidirectional iterator is forward iterator + something. And if type is not applicable then compiler would generate proper diagnostic not cryptic messages within 100+ errors?